# Can I compare an untracked file with a remote repository?

Tags: git, diff, git-diff

I have a file, which is not in a git repository, which was a copy of a file that's now in a repository on github.  Can git show me the differences between these files?

I tried something like `git diff master@https://github.com/.../....git -- myfile` but I don't think that's remotely right, and I can't seem to figure out how to reference such a remote file from the man pages.

I'd rather avoid checking out the whole remote repository or downloading the raw file just to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it's possible. Git's network protocol is mostly limited to moving objects around by design. However it is possible to make cloning the repository faster.

You can make the clone a little faster by doing a shallow clone, just the files without history, with `git clone --depth 1 <url>`.

---

Alternatively, you can take advantage of a Github feature and diff with the raw copy of the file.  Use `curl -s` to download the file and pipe it to `diff - yourfile`.

```
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/evalEmpire/piledriver/master/.travis.yml | diff -u - .travis.yml
```